# Am I doing shirk?

Tags: shirk

Suppose that someone says other religion's gods'  name and shirk sentences and blow on my clothes in my absence and after that I am wearing it,so am I  committing shirk unknowingly?

Comment: Is this a serious question? Why should you be committing shirk?

Comment: Am I not doing shirk because I am using that clothes?

Comment: Are you using it because somebody did what he did? If no why should it be shirk if yes then ...

Comment: No j don't know what he did with my clothes then....

Comment: Don't waste our time as your question is already covered and the answer is obvious anyways.

Comment: Ok thank you jazakallah khair

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu Alaikum,

If you ever do anything haram without knowing, then Allah is always forgiving. He's merciful to us and knows that you didn't mean to commit a sin. May Allah guide us to the right path.

Answer (score -1):

It is shirk if someone believes in the false gods that other religions believe in. Someone who believes that there is another god other than Allah (swt) alone or believes that there is other to be worshipped other than him has done shirk